# Facebook React Native SDK login button too small

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-ios

The default login button for Facebook's React Native SDK isn't rendering all of the text "Continue with Facebook" and instead it cuts off at the "k" in Facebook. It seems like the container needs to be tad larger to render the logo and entire text. After logging in, the text "Log out" fits fine.

I know that this button can be customized, but this should be fine out of the box. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: please show some code

Comment: <LoginButton
          publishPermissions={["publish_actions"]}
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
         
            }
          }
          onLogoutFinished={() => alert("logout.")}/> same issue